# Limit Google Autocomplete Place Search API for specific country using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to limit Google Autocomplete Place Search API  for specific country for example Bangladesh using objective-c. Here is my code

```
 APICommunicator *api = [[APICommunicator alloc] init];
             _searchTermArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSDictionary *arr = [api getGoogleAPIArrByPOST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&region=BD@&types=geocode&key=%@",searchTerms,API_KEY]  parameter:nil];
            NSString *areaName;
            for (areaName in arr) {
                _searchTermArray=[[arr valueForKey:@"predictions"]valueForKey:@"description"];



            }

          //  _searchTermArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arr];
            NSLog(@"%@",[_searchTermArray description]);
```

But unable to limit it by country. I will be grateful if anyone help me with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this url for getting result in specific country
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=xyz&region=BD&components=country:BD&types=geocode&key=yourapi_key

Comment: How can I restrict it for a particular city ?